# C# GetHashCode for binning

Tags: c#, binning

I would like to bin a set of objects, in particular Point types with an x and y value so that I can count the number of points at each x, y pair that exists in the set of Points. The max value of x and y is [-1000,1000] so it is easy enough to generate a unique hash code for each possible point.

For the actual binning process, can this be done using a Dictionary. Does the GetHashCode get used for this when I add/lookup a Point to the dictionary?

Is there a better way to do binning?

Comment: No problem.  Override GetHashCode() to return x + 1000* y and use `Dictionary<Point, int>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, unless you pass a custom instance to provide hash codes and check equality when you construct the `Dictionary` instance, `GetHashCode` and `Equals` methods for your type will be used.

To provide your custom hashing mechanism, you can simply override `GetHashCode` and `Equals`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Simple things like this can be super useful!